# GitLab Auto Deploy to FTP

Tags: docker, gitlab

can anyone help me with this error?
I am new to GitLab and still studying things. I think I missed something on this configuration?

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get --quiet update --yes
    - apt-get --quiet install --yes lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -reverse --verbose --delete build/ /FTP/test-deploy --ignore-time --parallel=20"
```

This is the log

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.6.0 (5316d4ac)
  on dedicated runner Lban3VJA
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.6 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.6 ...
Using docker image sha256:9a2d45e2219e289f367dce5bace14f8f80495038bf16506860e3808d11afe34a for ruby:2.6 with digest ruby@sha256:634a743c2cb4b51cc9d887103c383e70aef4040b0540fa295d7aed9659320c6d ...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on runner-lban3vja-project-2-concurrent-0 via gitlab...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/test-project/.git/
Checking out e5bae75d as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:30
Using docker image sha256:9a2d45e2219e289f367dce5bace14f8f80495038bf16506860e3808d11afe34a for ruby:2.6 with digest ruby@sha256:634a743c2cb4b51cc9d887103c383e70aef4040b0540fa295d7aed9659320c6d ...
$ apt-get --quiet update --yes
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [39.4 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [102 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [2592 B]
Fetched 8487 kB in 11s (808 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
$ apt-get --quiet install --yes lftp
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lftp
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 725 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2309 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 lftp amd64 4.8.4-2+b1 [725 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 725 kB in 17s (42.1 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package lftp.
(Reading database ... 22741 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lftp_4.8.4-2+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lftp (4.8.4-2+b1) ...
Setting up lftp (4.8.4-2+b1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
$ lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror --reverse --verbose --delete build/ /FTP/test-deploy --ignore-time --parallel=20"
mirror: Access failed: /builds/root/test-project/build: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**ERROR**

> mirror: Access failed: /builds/root/test-project/build: No such file or directory

I think I missed something here?

My goal is to transfer every file inside of "test-project" repository.

Comment: If my answer helped - please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a Gitlab problem, rather an `lftp` one:

```
Access failed: /builds/root/test-project/build: No such file or directory
```

tells you that there is no `build` folder inside the current working directory. Instead - you want to mirror the contents of the `.`, which is the current working directory and where the gitlab project is already cloned.

So, your `lftp` should work with something like this:

```
lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror --reverse --verbose --delete ./ /FTP/test-deploy --ignore-time --parallel=20"
```

Comment: It works, but now I have another problem no files has been uploaded. T_T